# how to fix AttributeError: 'HTMLParserTreeBuilder' object has no attribute 'initialize_soup'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'HTMLParserTreeBuilder' object has no attribute 'initialize_soup'
```

I was trying to find the xpath for the checkbox of M in eBay ([link](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=mens%20shirt&_sacat=0))

I am using spyder and I have imported bs4 everywhere I can.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

web_page = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=mens+shirt&_sacat=0')
web_soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.text, 'html.parser')
checkbox = soup.find(class_='cbx x-refine__multi-select-checkbox')
checkbox_names = checkbox.find_all('a')

for check in checkbox_names:
    print(check.prettify())
```

I was expecting an output like this

```
<a href="/web/20121007172955/https://www.nga.gov/cgi-bin/tsearch?artistid=11630">
 Zabaglia, Niccola
</a>
```

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-beautiful-soup-and-python-3) to help me with my code.

Comment: I can't find `Zabaglia, Niccola` anywhere on the website, could you please upload a screenshot where you see it.

Comment: The first issue I see here is you are using a `soup` variable as your stored object, when you have in fact stored it as `web_soup`. The second issue is the class is `'cbx x-refine__multi-select-checkbox '`, not `'cbx x-refine__multi-select-checkbox'`. A very subtle difference, but the way as is, would not find any elements. The third issue is it will not find any `<a>` tags as the page is dynamic and would need to be rendered first (can use Selenium to do that). But my suggestion is, since you are following the tutorial and learning, find a webpage that is not rendered dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `soup.find(class_='cbx x-refine__multi-select-checkbox')` is selecting actually only the first element with the class `cbx x-refine__multi-select-checkbox`

So to get the url to the "M Size Shirt", you could do the following:

**CODE:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

web_page = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=mens+shirt&_sacat=0')
web_soup = soup(web_page.text, 'html.parser')
links = web_soup.find_all('a', {'class':'cbx x-refine__multi-select-link'})
for l in links:
    checkbox = l.find('input',{'class':'cbx x-refine__multi-select-checkbox '})
    if checkbox and 'M' == checkbox.get('aria-label'):
        #FOUND
        print(l.get('href'))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=mens+shirt&_sacat=0&rt=nc&Size%2520%2528Men%2527s%2529=M&_dcat=185100
```

Comment: thank you for this sample and i apologize for my code having multiple errors hopefully next time it wil be better

Comment: @lifelesskoka No problem, if it's help you maybe you can upvote and accept the answer :-)